# Why does the pane title not line up with the menu items in a UWP NavigationView?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

As can be seen in the screenshot below, the pane title ("Test Application") doesn't line up with the menu items, and there's an unexplained gap between the pane title and the toggle button.

[image: Screenshot of bug]

I've used the example code from Microsoft Learn's [guidance on NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview) but the gap remains.

Is this intended behaviour? If so, why? If not, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `NavigationView` control from the **WinUI2 library** instead of the native UWP `NavigationView` control. Using the latest WinUI2 library could  get the most current styles, templates, and features for `NavigationView`.

See Get [Started with WinUI 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started) for more info about how to use WinUI2 library

Here is the code that I'm using

```
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"

 <Grid>
    <muxc:NavigationView PaneTitle="Nav Title">
        <muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Nav Item A"/>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Nav Item B"/>
            <muxc:NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Nav Item C"/>
        </muxc:NavigationView.MenuItems>

        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
    </muxc:NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

This is the result

[image]